# Can I release a scene before moving to another?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting, release, scene, autorelease

I am making an app for iPhone 4 and above. I know the iPhone 4 memory is low being around 150mb. I have 3 scenes. First scene welcome scene 50mb. The game play scene is 100mb and ending scene defeat scene is 50mb.

When starting the app memory goes to 50mb ram. Then starting the game play memory goes to 100mb. If defeated goes to ending scene 50mb, adding up to 200mb. This is terrible because the iPhone 4 can't support that much and it would crash.

I want to know if I can release the scenes in each transition so I can support different versions of iPhone. Sorry for the spelling and if this has already been asked PLEASE supply me with the link as I could find a answer to my problem. I have tried auto-release but still it doesnt get the job done. Maybe it later but too late, I need it to just happen.

Answer (score 0):

i have solved the issue thankfully :D how? well i added a code to minimize load on ios's below 8 which the iphone 4 cant go above, there at ios 7: the code:

```
 if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"8.0")) {

 }

 if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {


 }
```

i also added 1x,2x,3x images, even thou they were their before but the most obvious one was the umm lol simulator that was being run at iphone 6plus  <:D and um that loaded the 3x so 200 mb on the iphone 4 now fully optimised only 60mb at most, :D, success!! next issue the nsuserdefault cant get that to save a simple bool :(